# How to write optimization problem in one column of a scientific paper?

Tags: equations

[image]
Hi, I have utilized the subequation environment in order to write the optimization equations as shown in the attached picture. Furthermore, I have utilized the rule command to insert the horizontal lines before and after Model 1: AC-OPF, but there is an excessive space between Model 1_AC-OPF and lower line. I think this is not the nice way to develop the model shown in attached pic. Can somebody show me how this model can be developed in a nice way?

```
        \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{subequations}
    \noindent\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt} 
    \normalsize Model 1: AC-OPF \\
    \noindent\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}
    \begin{flalign}
    &\hspace{7.5em}\mathbf{M1:}\hspace{0.3em}\underset{\varphi}   {\mathbf{minimize}}\ f(\varphi)\\
    &\hspace{0em}\mathbf{variables:} \hspace{0.5em}\mathbf{S}_{g_i} \hspace{0.2em} (\forall i \in N), \mathbf{W}_{ii} \hspace{0.2em} (\forall i \in N), \mathbf{W}_{ij} \hspace{0.2em} (\forall i,j \in N) \nonumber
   \end{flalign}
   $\hspace{0.5em}  \mathbf{subject} \hspace{0.3em} \mathbf{to:}   \hspace{0.3em} (\ref{Gen_Limit}) \hspace{0.3em} \& \nonumber$
    \begin{flalign}
    &\mathbf{S}_i = \sum_{k:i\sim k} \text{diag}(\mathbf{W}_{ii}-\mathbf{W}_{ik}^H)\mathbf{Y}_{ik}^H \hspace{1.5em} \forall i \in N\\
    & \hspace{5em}\underline{V}_i^2\leq \mathbf{W}_{ii}\leq \overline{V}_i^2 \hspace{3.1em} \forall i \in N\\
    & tan(\underline{\theta_{ij}})\hspace{0.2em} \Re(\mathbf{W}_{ij})\leq \Im({\mathbf{W}}_{ij})\leq tan(\overline{\theta_{ij}})\hspace{0.2em}\Re(\mathbf{W}_{ij}) \nonumber\\ 
    & \hspace{15em}\forall (i,j) \in E \\
    & \hspace{7em}\mathbf{W}_{ij} = \mathbf{W}_{ji}^H
    \end{flalign}
    \noindent\rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{subequations}
    \end{document}
```

I have to write the equations in a 2 column scientific paper, so please show me the way of putting everything in 1 column.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text, don't use in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{subequations}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}
Model 1: AC-OPF \\
\rule[1ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}

\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}
\begin{flalign}
\textbf{M1: } \underset{\varphi}{\mathbf{minimize}}\ f(\varphi)&&& 
\end{flalign}
\textbf{variables: } 
    $\mathbf{S}_{g_i}\;(\forall i \in N)$,
    $\mathbf{W}_{ii} \;(\forall i \in N)$,
    $\mathbf{W}_{ij} \;(\forall i,j \in N)$

\smallskip        
\textbf{subject to:} (\ref{Gen_Limit}) \& 
\begin{flalign}
\quad
& \mathbf{S}_i = \sum_{k:i\sim k} \diag(\mathbf{W}_{ii} - \mathbf{W}_{ik}^H) \mathbf{Y}_{ik}^H
    & \forall i \in N       && \\
& \underline{V}_i^2\leq \mathbf{W}_{ii}\leq \overline{V}_i^2
    & \forall i \in N       && \\
& \tan(\underline{\theta_{ij}})
    \Re(\mathbf{W}_{ij})    \leq 
    \Im({\mathbf{W}}_{ij})\leq 
    \tan(\overline{\theta_{ij}})
    \Re(\mathbf{W}_{ij})    \hspace{-8em}&& \\
&   
    & \forall (i,j) \in E   && \notag\\ 
& \mathbf{W}_{ij} = \mathbf{W}_{ji}^H
                            &&
\end{flalign}
\rule[1ex]{\columnwidth}{1pt}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Can you please tell me what does lipsum package do? Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman, `lipsum` generate dummy text by which is simulated a text in your document. in your document you had to remove it .